# How do I tell conda/mamba to use windows/linux/osx channels that are different from the system OS?

Tags: python, conda, cross-platform, virtual-environment, mamba

I would like to help someone solve their problem with installing a particular `mamba` environment: [New mamba environment force torch CPU and I don't know why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74234628/new-environment-force-torch-cpu-and-i-dont-know-why)

However, they use Windows, and I am on macOS.

How can I tell `mamba` to use `pytorch/win-64` and `conda-forge/win-64` channels instead of `osx-arm` subchannels?

I know I can specify channels using `-c` but how do I specify the system subdirectory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CONDA_SUBDIR` variable works well for this. For example,

```bash
CONDA_SUBDIR=win-64 mamba create -dn foo -c pytorch -c conda-forge pytorch
```

Comment: So `CONDA_SUBDIR` does two things: set `--override-channels` and adds `win-64` as channel. Great to know - it was almost mystical to me how it worked.

Comment: No, it doesn't imply `--override-channels`; just avoids having to specify both a platform-specific subdirectory to channel arguments (including `noarch`).

Comment: Got it, it only overrides the subdir (e.g. `osx-64`) part but not the channel-proper.

Answer (score 1):

One simply needs to add the subdirectory to the channel, like `-c conda-forge/win-64` and use `--override-channels` as well to make sure the default channels are not used.

To emulate `mamba` running on windows, this works:

`mamba create -n test -c pytorch/win-64 -c conda-forge/win-64 -c conda-forge/noarch --override-channels pytorch`