# Installing python arch on Windows fails - with Anaconda 32 bit

Tags: python, conda, arch

[This page](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/arch-py) shows how to install the `arch-py` package in a conda environment. The list of labels includes `win-64`, which makes me think that the same command should work also on Windows, just like the installation of `numpy` works.

I tried as suggested, but it fails:

```
(myarch) C:\Windows\System32>conda install -c conda-forge arch-py
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - arch-py

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-32
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I also tried by creating the environment and installing the package at the same time, but I got the same failure:

```
(base) C:\Windows\System32>conda create -c conda-forge -n myarch python numpy arch-py
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - arch-py

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-32
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-32
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: seems like conda is not searching the conda-forge/win-64 channel

Comment: Is there a way to check if that is the case and to force it to do it?

Comment: try setting the environment variable `CONDA_SUBDIR=win-64`  as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74273014/5666087

Comment: Shows the Conda **base** is for `win-32` platform. Is that really the case? This system is not x86_64? If not, then this answer should cover you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58014896/570918 (i.e., tell Conda to use `win-64`).

Comment: @merv - mmmh... i use an old 32 bit cad application, i interact with it with excel and python, so our company has 32 bit office and python on all computers... i may have told anaconda to work with 32 bits when i first installed it (i don't remember and i don't know if it's even possible), and now it may remember about it even when i create new environments that don't need to be 32 bit... i will investigate in that direction, thanks

Comment: @merv if you want credit for the answer, please add one, otherwise i will mark mine as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @merv suggested, the problem was caused by the original Anaconda installation being 32 bit. I have updated the title to help any future Anaconda 32 bit users.

By following the steps listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58014896/1899628), I was able to solve this problem:

```
conda create —n arch-py
conda activate arch-py
conda config --env --set subdir win-64
conda install python=3.10
conda install numpy
conda install arch-py
```